# How to avoid a "N+1 behavior" in a tree table query in Peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

I have a tree data-structure represented by a parent-link foreign key and I want to use the backref avoiding Peewee do a new query each time.

The model I'm using is like this:

```
from peewee import *

class Table(Model):
    name = TextField()
    parent = ForeignKeyField('self', null=True, backref='children')

Table.create_table()

root = Table.create(name="root", parent=None)
A1 = Table.create(name="A1", parent=root)
A2 = Table.create(name="A2", parent=root)
B1 = Table.create(name="B1", parent=A1)
```

I need to get a Dictionary with all the sub-three from some element.

I try this:

```
query = Table.select().where(Table.name == "root")
tree = [model_to_dict(a, backrefs=True, recurse=True) for a in query]
```

And I get this:

```
[{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'root',
    'parent': None,
    'children': [
        {'id': 2,'name': 'A1'},
        {'id': 3,'name': 'A2'}
    ]
}]
```

But it has two problems: 1) it gives me only the direct children intead of all the descendants tree. 2) It hits several times the database.

Is there any way to get the completed sub-tree withou having a N+1 problem http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#nplusone?

Answer (score 1):

Your only real option is to use a recursive common-table expression. There is a section in the docs that may be helpful, as it deals exactly with this type of query:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#recursive-ctes

The query examples also have a recursive CTE example:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_examples.html#find-the-upward-recommendation-chain-for-member-id-27

Comment: I have tried it. But I have not managed to get a nested dictionary. I suppose I can use a recursive CTE to get all the descendants and then transform the result in nested dictionary, but I thought Peewee could do that form me in a more elegant way.

Comment: The database cursor returns row tuples. Any recursive CTE will still just yield a list of flat tuples. Databases are not hierarchical - they are relational. Any hierarchical transformations will need to be done on your end.